# Error message: Unknown database 'someweb_production' (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm trying to run this web aplication of Ruby on Rails with Apache using Phusion Passenger. I already configured the httpd.conf file.

I also have another aplication which runs with 'rails server' commmand, and it's connecting to the development database. However, i don't understand why the aplication which runs with apache it's trying to connect to a production database that i didn't create yet instead development as it should be.

What i have to configure to make my Ruby on Rails application run as development?

Answer (score 0):

Apache with Phusion provide a production level web server environment, `rails server` (WEBrick) is a simple web server that lets you test locally.  You typically use one or the other on a given machine.  But not always :-)

But to answer your question, which database is used by Rails is determined by the RAILS_ENV variable, which is by default, one of `production`, `development` or `test`.

When you create a new rails application, a default database configuration is created in the file `app/config/database.yml` -- there are separate sections that provide necessary parameters for connecting to your database(s).  Other environment-specific configurations may be specified either in the `environment.rb` or in `app/config/environments/<name>.rb`.

In your Passenger config, you can set the RAILS_ENV variable as documented here http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env.

I just realized also that it seems like Passenger is looking for production (expecting the db name to be `someweb_production`) -- chances are you have to run a `bundle exec rake db:migrate` in the production environment in order to (create and) initialize the database.  You may need to pass the environment parameter in this case also.

For your local config (`rails server`) the server will look for a shell environment variable named `RAILS_ENV`, and you can also pass a specific environment on the command line e.g. `rails server --environment=development`.  I think if neither is specified, rails server defaults to `development`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didn't include the following lines in the Apache conf file:

```
RailsEnv development
RackEnv development
```